# Why did the plot instantly skip from the monster's escape to the townspeople's defense preparations?

Tags: plot-explanation, continuity, young-frankenstein

The next scene after the monster escapes from the castle in *Young Frankenstein* does instantly show the townspeople preparing for him (the scene with Helga's grandpa and mother) which means that they are already informed of his escape. Why did they skip the plot so instantaneously without displaying the story behind it?

Comment: Probably because there wasn't anything to be shown that would have added to the story.